# Expectation value with respect to the binomial distribution

Tags: probability-or-statistics

How do I compute the following expectation value concerning the [Digamma function $\psi(k)$](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma-Funktion):

$$\langle k\, \psi(k)\rangle=\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose{k}}\,p^k(1-p)^{n-k}\, k \,\psi(k)$$

I have tried:

```
Sum[Binomial[n, k] p^k (1 - p)^(n - k) k PolyGamma[k], {k, 0, n}]
```

but that gives

$$-(1-p)^n$$

which can not be true.

**EDIT:**

The closed form solution for $n\geq 1$ is

$$\langle k\, \psi(k)\rangle=p\, n\left(\log p+\psi(n)+B_{1-p}(n,0)\right)-(1-p)^n$$

In Mathematica code:

```
f[p_,n_] = p n (Log[p] + PolyGamma[n] + Beta[1-p,n,0]) - (1-p)^n
```

Comment: I wonder if you can't get there from here:  `PolyGamma[0] = ComplexInfinity`.  Changing `Sum` to `Table` and putting in a specific value for `n` might shed some light on the issue.

Comment: Might one avoid the `PolyGamma[0]` problem by summing over `k=1` to `n`, since the `k=0` term does not add to the summation?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork That would avoid the `Polygamma[0]` problem but then a truncated binomial distribution would need to be used.  Otherwise it would not be the expectation if the sum of the probabilities don't add up to 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `n == 0`evaluate the limit

```
Limit[Binomial[0, k] p^k (1 - p)^-k k PolyGamma[k], k -> 0]

(* -1 *)
```

Include assumptions

```
ex[n_, p_] = 
 Assuming[{0 <= p <= 1, Element[n, Integers], n > 0}, 
  Sum[Binomial[n, k] p^k (1 - p)^(n - k) k PolyGamma[k], {k, 0, n}] // 
   Simplify]
```

[image]

Although the assumptions excluded `n == 0`, evaluating this expression for `n == 0` is consistent with the limit above

```
ex[0, p]

(* -1 *)

{#, ex[#, p]} & /@ Range[0, 10] //
   Simplify //
  Prepend[#, 
    Style[#, 14, Bold] & /@ {"n", 
      "〈k ψ(k)〉"}] & //
 Grid[#, Frame -> All] &
```

[image]

```
Plot[Evaluate@Table[Tooltip[ex[n, p], n], {n, 10, 0, -2}], {p, 0, 1}, 
 PlotLegends -> Placed[Range[10, 0, -2], {0.25, 0.65}],
 AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 14, Bold] & /@ {"p", 
     "〈k ψ(k)〉"})]
```

[image]

Note that if the assumptions include `n >= 0` then the result is the same as that without assumptions.

```
Assuming[{0 <= p <= 1, Element[n, Integers], n >= 0}, 
 Sum[Binomial[n, k] p^k (1 - p)^(n - k) k PolyGamma[k], {k, 0, n}] // 
  Simplify]

(* -(1 - p)^n *)
```

Comment: But your figure shows that the expectation is not $-(1-p)^n$ (except for $n=0$).  What am I missing?

Comment: @JimB - The last observation reflects how Mathematica might arrive at its result. I understand that the results are different under the different assumptions.

Comment: OK. Got it now.  It does seem that using `Limit[k PolyGamma[k], k->0] = -1` for `k PolyGamma[k]` when `k=0` for all values of `n` gives what you show in the table and figure.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `PolyGamma[k]` has a simple pole in zero, i.e.
`PolyGamma[k] ~ -1/k +O(1)`. Therefore
`k*PolyGamma[k]` is regular in zero and has value -1.

For your purpose you could define a function regular in zero, say

```
jj[x_] := Piecewise[{{-1, x <= 0}, {x*PolyGamma[x], x > 0}}]
```

So that the expectation value of jj i.e.

```
Sum[Binomial[n, k] p^k (1 - p)^(n - k) jj[k], {k, 0, n}]
```

is OK for n=0. This method reproduces the above table.

For generic n there is no simple expression. One could however easily 
infer that

```
Sum[n] ~ -1 -n*(EulerGamma-1)*p + O(p^2)
```